# System of separable diff. eqns, explicit solution and curves, Lotka-Volterra model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matlab, mathematical-modeling

In the [book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yLgPBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=dynamical+systems+maple+lynch&hl=en&sa=X&ei=By2VVaW4IMHksgHl5oHwDg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dynamical%20systems%20maple%20lynch&f=false) on p.68 is a system of differential equations for a Predator-Prey model (Lotka-Volterra) given as:

$$
\dot x=x(\alpha-c\gamma) \\ 
\dot y=y(\gamma x -\delta)
$$

On the next page, it is said that **the system has solution curves (the differential equation is separable) given by $x^\delta y^\alpha e^{-\gamma x} e^{-cy} = K$, where $K$ is a constant.**

I tried to do the separation of variables like this:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(\gamma x -\delta)}{x(\alpha-c\gamma)} \\
\frac xy = \frac{dx(\gamma x -\delta)}{dy(\alpha-c\gamma)} \\
$$

But the integration is not easy at all

$$\int \frac {dy(\alpha-c\gamma)}y = \int \frac{dx(\gamma x -\delta)}x$$

So I tried using MATLAB as `dsolve([diff(x)==x*(a - c*y), diff(y)==-y*(d - g*x)])` which resulted to `Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.`

Can anyone please tell me how to get that solution in bold by hand, by MATLAB or both ways please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of variables is fine.

Note
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y(
\gamma x-\delta)}{x(\alpha - cy)} &\implies \displaystyle\int^y\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{y'} - c \right)dy'
 = \displaystyle\int^x \left(\gamma -\dfrac{\delta}{x'}\right)dx' \\
&\implies \alpha\log y-cy=\gamma x-\delta \log x+\log K \\
&\implies \exp[\log x^\delta y^\alpha -\gamma x - cy] = K\\
&\implies \boxed{x^\delta y^\gamma e^{-\gamma x}e^{-cy} = K}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you @FH93 for the response. It looks good, and I was able to follow all the steps now, apart from why is integration constant $log\,K$ instead of just $K$. Could you please also explain why the apostrophe notation is used in $x',y',dx'$ and $dy'$ ? Thank you.

Comment: Constants of integration are arbitrary - you can call them whatever you like. In this case, I chose to denote the constant by $\log K$ because I saw that it would line up with your notation; if you're not comfortable with this, you can write it as $+C$ and then you'll end up with an $e^C$ on the RHS instead (which you can later just call K, to line up with their notation).

Comment: The "primes" are being used to distinguish between the dummy variables of integration $(x', y'$ etc$)$ and the actual variables $x,y$. The choice of notation for the dummy variables is irrelevant (as long as they don't interfere with the actual variables, $x,y$, to avoid ambiguity); I could have just as easily called them $u,v, du,dv$, for example - integration is independent of the way in which one labels the variables of integration.